# creating top level package on gorm orm for micro services in golang

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

We are a startup tech company. we use Golang as are primary language for our micro services and `gorm` orm as our interface to connect to our `PostgreSQL` database.

Currently we have multiple micro services with multiple developers working on them. The problem however is that since there are many ways to do one thing in `gorm`, everybody did their own way of writing queries on the database. So some people used the `.Table()` function to do queries and some other just passed the `.Model()` to figure out the table itself.

So now the code is not standard and we want to have a standard way to do queries on our databases. We figured that if we could have a package like a library which provides a `orm`'s interfaces to us to use (so that if we wanted to change the `orm` or don't use any we didn't have to change all the codes) in a standard manner, it solves the problem.

But We've never created such a thing, we basically have little idea how to approach the problem and if any library exists that has done such a thing or not? also we are struggling to standard way to do queries in Golang so if you could share your ides on how to develop such a system that can even have the potential to be announced public, we would thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had **exactly** the same problem, we are using `gorm` for different applications and with different databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite).

We *naively* decided to abstract gorm using what we called a `Storage` interface, this interface has more or less the basic operations that you require from any orm. It looked like this:

```golang
type Storage interface {
    Create(object interface{}) error
    Retrieve(object interface{}, queries ...Query) error
    Update(object interface{}) error
    Delete(object interface{}) error
}
```

At the beginning of the development, it served us very well and we could even implement this interface using a normal file and it would just work.

**BUT**

After a couple of months, we started to notice its limitations. There are operations that can be done in `gorm` that we can't do using our interface. So, obviously, we decided to extend the interface to have more functionality. Again, this bought us another couple of months until we realized: *the only way to have all the functionality of `gorm` is to provide an interface for everything `gorm` provides which is not exactly why we started writing this package*.

Since this interface is used everywhere, we decided *as an interim solution* to extend the interface and add a function that returns the `gorm.DB` object so that we can directly use it again.

Moral of the story, I would strongly advice against building such an interface. Use the time to help with the development of `gorm`'s [v2](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/tree/v2_dev) which should be coming out soon according to this [post](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/2886#issue-565836194).

Answer (score 2):

I think that wrapping such a complex thing as gorm is a complex task and if you are not clear on how to approach it, you should better avoid doing that.

Generally, I would suggest first figuring out what you want to enforce and only then deciding on how do you want to do that, having clear requirements in mind. Grabbing a tool before you know what exactly you want to do is a reliable way to make things worse and not better. Here are steps you can follow:

1. Start with documenting your code standards and pointing people to them on code reviews in case they don't comply;
2. Automate check of whatever you can check formally into Continuous Integration pipelines (GitHub Actions, GitLabCI, TravisCI, CircleCI, and things like that);
3. If and only if things above don't work, look into creating your own wrapper which would enforce particular style usage for developers.

   By the last step, you should have already a pretty decent understanding of what exactly is missing and then it would be much easier to figure out how to fix it.